# Ubuntu upgrade from virtualbox

Tags: system-installation

I wish to know if i can hit the upgrade button on ubuntu installed in virtual box in order to update ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can upgrade Ubuntu within a virtual machine. However, be sure that there is enough disk space available. The upgrade tool may underestimate the required space on occasion. Around 3GB should be enough, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

**Make a snapshot.** Make sure that you have enough disk space. Then hit that button! If this fails, then return to the snapshot and you haven't lost anything except time.